# Indexing large video data file that comes in packets

Tags: video, video-processing, video-capture, lidar

I’m not sure if a word “indexing” is right in this context, but imagine this procedure. You get your video file not as a .mov or .mp4 but as a series of packets of a specific size lets say 1024 bytes. A packet contains the pixel intensities for 3 channels, arranged in a way that each packet fits lets say 2 full video frames and then 75% of the 3rd one. So the remaining 25% of the 3rd frame will come in the next packet together with 2 more frames and 50% of some next frame.

If i want to read images into memory does it make sense to put those packets together in a binary file and index the file to keep track of where an image starts and where it ends?

I see in terms of video where all frames have the same size it might be easier just to keep reading packets until a frame of known is complete, save it and then proceed to the next one. My problem is that my “video” is captured by LIDAR so the “frames” can contain different amount of points, thus weigh take slightly different size. However i know when the frame starts and ends, and i has something to do with the LIDAR rotation angle that i get from the packets.

Comment: It doesn’t matter. You can store one frame per file, concat the frames and store a separate table of their size, or just scan the file every time you read it. Or write the size before each frame in the stream. Or stick each frame in a protobuf.  Or a million other options. It totally depends on your application requirements and available resources.

Answer (score 0):

As @szatmary mentioned everything depends on application requirements. Since you know when a frame starts and ends, I would recommend you to create an array (list/vector/collection depends on what language you are using) and populate it with **frames**. Then you can do processing or rewrite it into files you can work with.